# Mounting using indermediate server and sshfs with autofs

Tags: proxy, automount, sshfs

I have a gateway machine (A) and the final machine (B). I have been able to ssh and sshfs to machine B through A using ProxyCommand in ~/.ssh/config. I have made it so that logging in doesn't require passwords using the ssh-copy-id command both machines. This works well and I can do from my machine:

sshfs user@B:/home/user mnt

I now want to use autofs to get the mounting happening on demand (I already do this for folders on machine A) but this doesn't seem to work. The folder for mounting is /mnt in this case. I tried running automount with the verbose and debug options and I see this:

```
handle_packet: type = 3
handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 96, name folder, request pid 6296
attempting to mount entry /mnt/folder
lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up folder
lookup_mount: lookup(file): folder -> -fstype=fuse,allow_other :sshfs\#user@B\:/home/user
parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=fuse,allow_other :sshfs\#user@B\:/home/user
parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: uid=1000,gid=1000,fstype=fuse,allow_other
parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote(":sshfs\#user@B\:/home/user") -> :sshfs#user@B:/home/user
parse_mount: parse(sun): core of entry: options=uid=1000,gid=1000,fstype=fuse,allow_other, loc=:sshfs#user@B:/home/user
sun_mount: parse(sun): mounting root /mnt, mountpoint folder, what sshfs#user@B:/home/user, fstype fuse, options uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other
do_mount: sshfs#user@B:/home/user /mnt/folder type fuse options uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other using module generic
mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mkdir_path /mnt/folder
mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mount -t fuse -o uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other sshfs#user@B:/home/user /mnt/folder
st_expire: state 1 path /mnt
expire_proc: exp_proc = 139950775805696 path /mnt
expire_proc_indirect: expire /mnt/folder
```

**Note**: I notice that when I try to mount manually with sshfs with /mnt as a mounting point I can't even when using sudo.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason why this was happening. Automount needs to run with sudo but root did not have the proxy setup in /root/.ssh/config so it could not access machine B (since it is only accessible through machine A). Once I updated /root/.ssh/config with the correct lines (using ProxyCommand) and reran the ssh-copy-id command with sudo I was able to get autofs working fine. I don't like answering my own question but instead of deleting it I will leave it here in case someone else finds the answer useful or in case there is a more elegant solution that I have missed.